# AppSync/GraphQL filter nested objects

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, vtl, aws-appsync-resolver

I have a DynamoDB table with the following structure

```
site           (String)
addresses      (List)
 |-> address   (String)
 |-> isCurrent (Boolean)
```

I want to filter a specific site for either current or all address(s).

```
query MyQuery {
  getSite(site: "site1", isCurrent: true) {
    site
    addresses{
       adress
       isCurrent
    }
```

the schema looks like

```
type Sites{
site: String!
addresses: [Address]
}

type Address {
address: String
isCurrent: Boolean
}

type Query{
getSite(site: String!, isCurrent:Boolean)
}
```

The Resolver I have

```
#if($ctx.args.isCurrent)
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Query",
    "query": {. // Filter for specific Site
        "expression": "#siteName = :siteNameByUser",
        "expressionNames": {
            "#siteName": "site"
        },
        "expressionValues": {
            ":siteNameByUser": {"S": $util.toJson($ctx.args.site)}
        }
    }, // Filter Current Address(s)
        "filter": {
        "expression": "addresses.isCurrent = :isActiveByUser",
        "expressionValues": {
            ":isActiveByUser": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.isCurrent)      
    }
  }
}
#else
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "GetItem",
    "key": {
        "site": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.site)
    }
}
#end
```

I'm not getting any results when I add filter ( it works without the filter or with isCurrent=False ).
I am trying to filter the inner objects in `Addresses` list based on a value user sends for isCurrent. Any help is much appreciated!

I tried writing a resolver with a filter condition on an inner value (addresses.isCurrent).

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Query",
    "query": {. // Filter for specific Site
        "expression": "#siteName = :siteNameByUser",
        "expressionNames": {
            "#siteName": "site"
        },
        "expressionValues": {
            ":siteNameByUser": {"S": $util.toJson($ctx.args.site)}
        }
    }, // Filter Current Address(s)
        "filter": {
        "expression": "addresses.isCurrent = :isActiveByUser",
        "expressionValues": {
            ":isActiveByUser": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.isCurrent)      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, DynamoDB does not let you filter on Complex object types like List of Maps (your case), see a related question: [DynamoDB: How to store a list of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505089/dynamodb-how-to-store-a-list-of-items)

I'd suggest changing your DynamoDB table data model if possible to `site`, `address`, `isCurrentAddress` to achieve what you are trying to do. Or you can
write logic in VTL response mapping template to filter your result set based on isCurrentAddress value. Btw AppSync recently launched [JavaScript resolvers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-reference-overview-js.html), go through that and see if that helps in writing your resolver logic simpler.